# Database maintenance plan fails to run every time

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, database-administration

I set up a DBMP for SS2008 and explicitly set it to run under a user that has the the `serveradmin` role.

The job (under sql server agent) generated from the plan is set to run under the same sql account, and I forced the job step to run as a windows admin account other than the default "SQL Server Agent Service account". Then I restarted sql server agent, but the job keeps failing, throwing this error:

```
SQLServer Error: 18456, Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. [SQLSTATE 28000]
```

I can't see what might be missing here... I'm explicitly telling SQL Server agent to run the job under a different account than `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: What account is your SQL Server Agent running as? Start> Run> services.msc right click SQL Server Agent service and go to properties.

Comment: Its running under Network Service. I already changed to admin account but problem still happens. The log in sql server says "Login access denied for the db i want to backup.." but the sql server account that i'm using is serveradmin and backup operator... should work fine i gues... :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting your SQL Server Agent to run as a different account. The account shouldn't have to be an admin account as long as you give it the proper permissions to any drives/shared directories it needs.

I'm not sure what you're doing to force a job to run as a particular account. The Server Agent                            has always been a bit finicky for me but when I run it as a domain account and assign that account the proper permissions I have very few issues.

Comment: Tried your tips but still not working. In job log history it complains about the login is denied for sql server user for that BD, but sql server account has serveadmin and backupoperator roles assigned to.